# shell_exec returns null ffmpeg for generating video thumb image

Tags: php, ffmpeg, shellexecute

I'm using ffmpeg for getting thumbnail image from video. Its working fine. But the shell_exec function returns null.

My command is,

```
$return=shell_exec('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i D:\wamp\www\test\demo.mov -f image2 -vframes 1 D:\wamp\www\test\test.jpg');
var_dump($return);
```

Can I get the return value from this? Kindly help me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

> The output from the executed command or NULL if an error occurred or
>   the command produces no output.
>
> Note: This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the
>   program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution
>   failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the
>   program exit code is required.

So either your program is failing, or it is successful but there is no output. Use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead of `shell_exec` to help you differentiate between these two cases. `exec` returns an exit code - if it's 0, it means success, and non-zero means fail.

```
exec('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i D:\wamp\www\test\demo.mov -f image2 -vframes 1 D:\wamp\www\test\test.jpg', $output, $exit_code);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($exit_code);
```